# -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] Can I pass nil for object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

Can I pass nil for the object argument of `-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:]` since the observers don't care who the sender is, or is it better practice to pass `self` for the object argument even though the observers aren't checking who sent the notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing nil won't harm anything. It's just nice to be able to know what sent the notification, even if current observers don't need to know and don't check it.